# Rust recursive updates to app_state with mutable reference

Tags: recursion, rust, reference, borrow-checker

I'm trying to build a parser that can recursively search a file system starting at a root directory (that is passed in by the user) and parse the files / directories within.

I have a Directory struct that holds references to parsed objects.  Parsed Objects are held in HashMaps which are part of a State struct.

```
pub struct Directory<'a> {
    pub pathname: String,
    pub child_dirs: Vec<&'a Directory<'a>>,
    pub child_files: Vec<&'a File>,
    pub child_templates: Vec<&'a Template>,
}
```

I have an app_state struct that holds all hash maps, like this (some hash maps omitted for brevity):

```
pub struct State<'a> {
    pub directory_hash: HashMap<OsString, Directory<'a>>,
    pub file_hash: HashMap<PathBuf, File>,
    pub template_hash: HashMap<PathBuf, Template>,
}
```

The `Parser::parse` signature looks like this:

`pub fn parse<'a>(root: &'a PathBuf, app_state: &'a mut app_state::State<'a>)`.

When Parser::parse is called it is passed a &PathBuf for the root directory. Each entry in the root directory will be looked at with two possibilities:

The entry is a directory:
===> 1) Create a new directory object.  2) Save the directory object into the correct `directory_hash`.  3) Parse the directory by calling the `Parser::parse` again with this as the root directory, and passing the app_state that we are currently using.

The entry is a file of some type:
===> 1) Parse the file into an object of the correct type.  2) Save the file into the correct hash map on app_state.  3)  Save a reference to it into the Vector on the current directory object.

**Problem**:  because this will recursively be called for anything with a depth greater than 1, I can't pass app_state to the `Parser::parse` method mutably again.

```
cannot borrow `*app_state` as mutable more than once at a time

mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of looprustc(E0499)
```

**Where I'm most stuck**:
This only occurs when I try to store REFERENCES in the vectors that live on the Directory struct.  If I were to store actual instances of those objects, this recursive call doesn't error. But I want to store everything in the master `app_state` object and only reference the rest from elsewhere.

Here's what my `Parser::parse` code looks like:

```
pub fn parse<'a>(root: &'a PathBuf, app_state: &'a mut app_state::State<'a>) {
        // Create a new directory object from the root
        let root_dir = Directory::new(root);

        // insert it into the directory hash
        let hash_key = root.clone().into_os_string();
        app_state.directory_hash.insert(hash_key, root_dir);

        // recurse over all entries in the directory
        let readable_dir = fs::read_dir(root);
        let readable_dir = match readable_dir {
            Ok(dir) => dir,
            Err(_e) => return, // handle errors that could occur
        };

        for item in readable_dir {
            let fpath = match item {
                Ok(file_path) => file_path,
                _ => continue, // handle errors that could occur
            };

            // if they are a directory, parse that directory
            if fpath.path().is_dir() {
                Self::parse(&fpath.path(), app_state);
            } else {
            // if not a directory, parse them according to their type
                let file_type = get_file_type(&fpath.path());
                Self::update_state(file_type, &fpath, app_state);
            }

        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me with this issue?  I've tried the suggestions that the compiler gives with adding lifetimes which in simpler situations I understand, but here I am either getting "doesn't live long enough" or "can't borrow mutably more than once" errors.

Can someone illuminate what's happening so I can better understand?

Answer (score 2):

This approach is inherently memory-unsafe: for instance, as the `directory_hash` grows, at some point its hash table will be rebuilt with different physical locations for the `Directory` entries, which would leave dangling references in the `child_dirs` entries. Rust will not allow this, so there is no way to solve this problem by adding/modifying the lifetimes annotations. Instead, a different way of structuring the data is needed.

Comment: I was actually sitting down to work on refactoring this now. Do you have any suggestion on an alternative structure? If I were to simply store the keys in the child_dirs vector that would be safe. My original code had me copying the keys and placing them in there, but I thought that was wasteful. Maybe that’s the actual solution? EDIT: I actually changed it to be this way because I was afraid cloning strings was inefficient / not idiomatic. But maybe that’s the right way to go?

Comment: Ok After thinking it over what you said makes sense and I should have seen it sooner.  I was bogged down into the errors the compiler was giving which were hiding this problem right in front of me.

So now I'm just storing the keys directly in the vectors of the Directory struct.  This does mean I have two copies of every key though (one in the State struct, and a copied one in the Directory struct).  Is this idiomatic, or is there a more efficient way to not copy this data?

Comment: There are many possible ways to do this without redundant copies. One way is to build up the Directory structures in one pass, letting them own all their contents (e.g. through `Box`es), and then in a second pass build the `HashMap`s with references into it. If you want or need to do it in one pass, then you could instead use an arena to own all the data and let both the `Directory`s and `HashMap`s reference into it. Or instead of an arena you could use `Rc`s instead of ordinary references, in both the `Directory` and `HashMap` structures.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, for that first approach (`Directory` owning its contents) there's no need for `Box`es as the `Vec`s already include the necessary indirection to keep the structure finite.